# CSS: Float over a clear

Tags: html, css

I have an item (element A) that I have set to `float:right`.

Unfortunately, another element on the page that another team wrote (element B) uses `clear:both`, which means that it ends up going below my element, creating an awkward white space.  Although the `clear:both` was written before I added my element and doesn't have it in mind, I would rather handle this from within my element than change someone else's CSS.

http://jsfiddle.net/2HwWw/

Is there a way to override clear:both so that my element doesn't get cleared, and the other team's item can stay next to mine?  Basically, I want element B and element A on the same line, but only through manipulating element A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
<div style="float:right;height:0;">Mine</div>
<div style="clear:both;">Theirs now</div>
<div style="height:50px" id="blankspaceforstackoverflow"></div>
<div style="float:right">Mine</div>
<div>Where I want this item, without changing its css.</div>
```

In your `div`, add:

```
height:0;
```

`div`'s will naturally resize in accordance with their content.

An exception to this rule is when the `div` contains floating elements. If this is the case you'll need to do a bit extra to ensure that the containing `div` clears the floats. You could use the `clearfix` method to do so.

**[More info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8554054/3739658)**

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2HwWw/7/)**

Comment: Sorry but I want to avoid changing their CSS.  That clear:none is there for a reason that does not have to do with my element; adding `clear:none!important` to their element may have unintended consequences w.r.t. its relationship with other elements on the page.

Comment: So to be clear you only want to change your element which is element A or the one you set to `float:right;`... correct?

Comment: Yes, I only want to change the first div (the one that says "mine") which is element A.

Comment: Updated it again :) with demo

Comment: Woah, that works.  Why does that work?  I would have thought that height would automatically set itself to the interior contents if it was bigger than the CSS specification, but I guess the CSS commmunicates "height: 0" to the other elements before giving the div its actual height?

Answer (score 2):

Add `clear:none` to the element so it doesn't get cleared. It should override your co-workers code and if not, use the `!important` attribute

Answer (score 0):

If i understand right, then this second element should not be floatting, so it will go underneath of previous element.

It can be [`inline-block`](http://jsfiddle.net/2HwWw/1/) or `inline-table` or even `block` and [`text-align:right;`](http://jsfiddle.net/2HwWw/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best way to do this is to add `clear: none` to the element, so it doesn't end up going below the floated element. You would benefit from learning more about the clear property. [The clear property](https://kolosek.com/css-clear-float/) is directly related to the [float property](https://kolosek.com/css-float/), so if you add `clear: both` to your element **it must go below** the floated elements.